# C++ Some misunderstand about union

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, unions

I am new to C++, and I have some questions about how the union works. This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



union S
{

    std::string str;
    int a;

~S() {}
};

int main()
{
    S s {};
    s.str = "hello";

std::cout << s.str << std::endl;
s.a = 3;
std::cout << s.a;
    std::cout << "This is my string : " <<  s.str << std::endl;
```

}

1. If I write " S s" instead of " S s{}", i have a error --> use of the deleted function S::S().
2. if I delete this line "~S() {}", i have a error --> use of the deleted function S::~S().

In this website, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union,
it is said that because I have a member (string) with a non default constructor/destructor, it will delete the default constructor and the default destructor of the union S. My question is :
**Why? I still don't understand why they delete the default constructor/destructor in C++.**

3. Also, I have heard it is important to explicitly call the  destructor if i want to switch the string to an integer because it will leads to the memory leak.My question is: Do I need to call the **union destructor** or the **string destructor**? In this code,if I need to call the union destructor, the destructor does nothing, so does that means my string won't be ereased?. If I need to call the string destructor, I don't know how to write the string destructor. Thank !

When i run this code, it shows me this :

```
hello
3
This is my string :
```

As I have expected, the last sentence "This is my string :" doesn't show me the string "hello" because I have overwrite "s.a = 3".
But, it seems s.str is empty. My questions is: **Why does s.str is empty**. Does it mean that the compiler has called automatically the destructor of my string. Thank!

I know there are alternative like boost or variant, but I still want to understand this.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `union`. Just stay away from it until you *absolutely* need something like it, which is rare these days.

Comment: I believe this is because a `union` does not actually have any "real" properties, they're effectively just casts, so it won't call any constructors or destructors. For example, if you had a `union` with `std::string` and `std::vector` then which, if any, destructors do you call? Clearly not both. Maybe not either. As such, putting things like `std::string` in there is highly problematic. Maybe someone can clarify on a more technical and/or spec-based level.

Comment: You should not be accessing a union member that you did not write to.  This is undefined behavior.  When you did `s.a = 3`, some of the string object's memory was overwritten.  Using non-trivial types inside a union is flaky, and to be avoided.  Maybe use `std::variant` instead.

Comment: They are asking a specific question about the mechanism by which inactive members are cleaned up. OP has already mentioned in the question the alternatives that are being suggested by the comments. It is not helpful to repeat in the comments what is already in the question. Please read the question fully before commenting.

Comment: On the deletion of the default constructor: Which member should be constructed, the `string` or the `int`? If you defaulted to the `string` because it was complicated, what about a union of `string` and `vector`? The union destructor would have to manually call the `string` destructor, one of the few times in the language that manually calling a destructor is a good thing. But... What if the union was strong an `int`? Can't destroy the `string` if there is no `string`.

Comment: Remember that both `a` and `str` occupy the same space in storage. `s.a = 3;` obliterates part of `str`'s book-keeping information by writing over it, rendering `str` invalid. Odds are good that the program didn't not print the string because the program crashed trying to interpret the `int` data as a `string`.

Comment: Note : Since `str` was never constructed, `s.str = "hello";` isn't valid. It is only by bad luck that the program didn't signal its brokenness by crashing here.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't understand why you say str was never constructed, I thought that when you assign the variable "str" to a string, it call the constructor -- > string(){}

Comment: Nope. Assignment is separated from initialization. Remember that with extremely rare exceptions you need both a copy constructor and an assignment operator if you need either of them.

Comment: @user4581301 But i wrote this : std::string str into my union, which call the constructor of the string right?

Comment: Friend, I'd have answered this question if I had an answer to why [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (at least I'm pretty sure it's aggregate initialization) allows this to work (or look like it works). It could be as simple as dumb luck that the default-constructed state of a `string` is all zeros.

Comment: Oh! Mother fud! There it is! *When a union is initialized by aggregate initialization, only its first non-static data member is initialized.* The `string` is guaranteed to be initialized. But if you changed the order so that the `int` was declared first, game over!

Comment: So correction, `str` was constructed and `s.str = "hello";` is valid, but before you `s.a = 3;` you MUST destroy `str` and then before you can `std::cout << "This is my string : " <<  s.str << std::endl;` you have to construct `str` again with [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new).

Comment: @user4581301 Why do I need to destroy my s.str when at the end of the main() scope,  the memory at the stack will be freed?

Comment: Any time you stop using `s` as a `string`, before assigning to `s.a` or when destroying `s` when `s` is being used as a `string`,  you need to call the destructor to end the lifetime of `str`. If it's because you're exiting `main` the benefits are questionable, but in general you run the risk of leaking any storage used by `str`. With a more complicated object, the results could be worse--like not releasing a mutex or not turning off the housekeeping robots who exterminate mankind in their obsessive need to clean your apartment.

Answer (score 2):

> If I write " S s" instead of " S s{}", i have a error --> use of the deleted function S::S().

`S` contains a `string` and this `string` must be constructed before it can be used. You've gotten around this with [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) which ensures the first member of the union will be correctly initialized.

Note that if `a` was the first member, it would be initialized rather than `str` and `s.str = "hello";` exhibits some of that classic [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) action.

You could also satisfy the compiler by adding a constructor that constructed the member you wished to use as the active member. Then it doesn't matter what order. As of C++20 you can use designated initializers, `S s{.str=""};`, to select which member to initialize and still use aggregate initialization to avoid writing a constructor

> if I delete this line "~S() {}", i have a error --> use of the deleted function S::~S().

Just as `str` must be constructed, you also need to have scaffolding to ensure that it can be destroyed if `str` is the active member when `s` is destroyed. This usually requires [more than just a union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#Union-like_classes) because you need some book-keeping to track the active member. Destroying `str` when it is not the active member is a [fatal mistake](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

> Also, I have heard it is important to explicitly call the  destructor if i want to switch the string to an integer because it will leads to the memory leak.My question is: Do I need to call the **union destructor** or the **string destructor**? In this code,if I need to call the union destructor, the destructor does nothing, so does that means my string won't be ereased?. If I need to call the string destructor, I don't know how to write the string destructor. Thank !

Any time you stop using `s` as a `string`, before assigning to `s.a` or when destroying `s` when `s` is being used as a string, you need to call the `string` destructor to end the lifetime of `str`.

So

```
s.a = 3;
```

needs to become

```
s.str.~string();
s.a = 3;
```

In addition, any time you want to make `str` the active member, you need to make sure it is constructed.

```
std::cout << "This is my string : " << s.str << std::endl;
```

needs to become

```
new (&s.str) std::string("I'm Baaaaaack!");
std::cout << "This is my string : " << s.str << std::endl;
```

and then, because `str` is the active member we should destroy it before `main` exits.

```
s.str.~string();
```

All bundled up we get,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union S
{

    std::string str;
    int a;

    ~S()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    S s{};
    s.str = "hello";

    std::cout << s.str << std::endl;
    s.str.~string();
    s.a = 3;
    std::cout << s.a;

    new (&s.str) std::string("I'm Baaaaaack!");
    std::cout << "This is my string : " << s.str << std::endl;
    s.str.~string();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! I have a last question: We use the destructor of the string. When i want to switch int to string, why i don't have to use the destructor of the primitive type int and why i don't have to use the constructor of int ?

Comment: @Emmanuelle `int` is so simple it needs no destructor. There's no clean-up or resources to release. `string` is not so fortunate.